# Print not showing in ipython notebook

Tags: python, printing, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am using `ipython` notebook (http://ipython.org/notebook.html) to do a demo and it seems like the print function is not working:

[image]

The commands in the above picture are rewritten here for clarity.

```
In [1]: 'hello world'
Out [1]: 'hello world'

In [2]: print 'hello world'
```

In short, there's no print output from the `[2]`.

Does anyone know whether it's a known bug? And does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: That's not a known bug as far as I know. If you can reproduce it, please do file [an issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues).

Comment: What is the cell type for the problematic cell?

Comment: I am having the same problem. To "fix" it, I have to re-start the kernel. Did you ever find a real fix for this?

Comment: @tmthyjames, nope, i haven't found a real fix. How do i restart the kernel?

Comment: @alvas At the top tab click Kernel > Restart.
I found a fix for my problem; not sure if it will apply to yours. Instead of running `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')` (which caused my printing problem) I just encoded the variables individually: `foo.encode('utf-8')`. Again, not sure if your problem is the same as mine but this fixed my issue.

Comment: I have the same problem when I use sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8').

Comment: it seems by default ipython cannot display unicode variable with python 2.7  ( e.g. refuse to print pandas dataframe with any non ascii character. )

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I had a similar printing problem when my first code cell was:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

Then I've commented the second and third lines like this:

```
import sys
#reload(sys)
#sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

Reset the kernel and re-ran the program and now my print statements are working properly.

Later on, I've found that when I was first having the printing problem, all print outputs were actually being sent to the ipython console terminal (on my Linux box), instead of being embed on the notebook.

Comment: Same for me. All print outputs are sent to the console. Also setting default encoding to utf8.

Comment: This is all well and good, but does not fix the problem if the call to `reload(sys)` is inside another python package (e.g. `pykwalify==1.5.2`). The other fix in this thread does, as it stores the outputstream, the does the reloading of sys (wherever it happens) and then resets the outputstream to the one you stored.

Comment: reload not defined

Answer (score 32):

I encountered a similar problem (the `reload(sys)` was in a package I imported).

My workaround was that at the top of the script, I import `sys`, and store `sys.stdout` in a separate variable, e.g. `stdout`.

Then I import all the other stuff, including the one that calls `reload(sys)`.

Then, at the end, I set `sys.stdout = stdout`, which redirects the output back to the IPython notebook

Comment: This should be the correct answer.  The answer above doesn't solve the issue if you need the default encoding to be utf8.  The real problem is that by reloading sys, it resets the stdout to the console, so you need to reset it back as shown here.

Answer (score 27):

Taking what @JoostJM has said, which works, and putting it as code:

```
import sys
stdout = sys.stdout
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
sys.stdout = stdout
```

Changing the default encoding directs the output to the console, this sets it back to the jupyter notebook.

Comment: print("Hello World") if using Python 3

Answer (score 2):

Another source of this problem can be due to "untrusted" notebooks. In my case, I downloaded source files from GitHub and when execute the cells, no output was shown. It turns out that the notebook was not trusted. So, I clicked on the menu `File`, then `Trust Notebook`. This security check by Jupyter is to avoid executing malicious code chunks hidden in the cells.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Python 3, so the solution is a bit different for me.

```
import sys
stdout = sys.stdout

# some functions that mess up sys.stdout

sys.stdout = stdout
```