# How to watch variable of a .ipynb script with Jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have following .ipynb file loaded with Jupyter. I can run it, and it seems to work fine.

[image]

However, I don't know how to watch variable values. For example, for following lines, how do I see the value of `gain` ?

```
gain = calculate_information_gain(train_data, train_labels)

print(gain)
```

I am using Windoes 10 and Python 3.5. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Add a new new cell below and do `gain` or `print(gain)`. It should output the value of variable `gain`

Comment: @MrPyCharm Thanks but it seems not working. I have already had print(gain) in the original script, and it does not print.

Comment: Maybe this post could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494182/print-not-showing-in-ipython-notebook-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. print is always an option
2. Memory usage

What's up with print ? do you want to track memory usage in whole. If that's the case you will be needing a library like memory_profiler.

3. Simple profiling memory size of objects

Simpler profiling memory size when using other data structures something like 
is useful http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504-compute-memory-footprint-of-an-object-and-its-cont/

---

But finally your question is similar to this one answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13404866/1951298