# dataframe head() works but print doesn't

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe bus_rev and if I run bus_rev.head() in a jupyter notebook it displays the first few rows, but if I run print(bus_rev[0:3]) or print bus_rev[0:3] it returns nothing.  I have the output from bus_rev.dtypes below, can anyone tell me what's going on?

Code:

```
bus_rev.dtypes
```

Output:

```
user_id          object
business_id      object
stars_x           int64
address          object
attributes       object
categories       object
city             object
hours            object
is_open           int64
latitude        float64
longitude       float64
name             object
neighborhood     object
postal_code      object
review_count      int64
stars_y         float64
state            object
good_reviews       bool
dtype: object


Update (didn't work):

import sys
stdout = sys.stdout
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
sys.stdout = stdout

print(bus_rev3.head())


Import Code:

from collections import Counter
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd

t1 = datetime.now()

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

reviews = ''

with open('dataset/review.json','r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines()[0:100000]:
        reviews += line

testdf = pd.read_json(reviews,lines=True)

print(datetime.now() - t1)
```

Comment: What is printed when you call `head()`?

Comment: print always returns None.

Comment: @MaorVeitsman  Thank you for getting back to me.  head() returns the first 5 records with the values for each column, none of the columns are missing values in first 5 records.

Comment: @AndyHayden  I have other dataframes in the same notebook, when I use the same print command with them I get the first few records from those dataframes.

Comment: What gets printed when you get the shape?

Comment: @MaorVeitsman bus_rev.shape returns (69, 18)

Comment: What do you get when your run `print bus_rev`?

Comment: @MaorVeitsman print bus_rev and print(bus_rev) return nothing.  It just updates the number to the right of the cell in the jupyter notbook, but nothing is returned below the cell.  Example, In [54]

Answer (score 0):

What are you importing at the beginning of your script? It seems like `reload(sys)` has caused problems for other people in the past.

[Print not showing in ipython notebook - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494182/print-not-showing-in-ipython-notebook-python)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I tried one of the tips from the post.  It didn't work, I added the code in an update to the original post.  I also added the code I used to load the json data.  Something I noticed when I ran the load script, it didn't display the time it took to run code.

Comment: I saved the dataframe out to a pickle file and restarted the kernel.  Now it prints.  So like the link you sent suggested I think it had something to do with the step where I set the default encoding.  Thank you!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help :)