# No output - Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

To begin, I am using MacOSX with a chrome browser.

I am unable to read any output when executing a simple print statement.

I began by creating a simple file named "hello.py"

```
print("hola")
```

I then convert that to the ipython notebook format using jupytext

```
jupytext --to notebook hello.py
```

I then ran `jupyter notebook`, however I receive no outputs.

I have tried various methods such as [Print not showing in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494182/print-not-showing-in-ipython-notebook).

According to a comment elsewhere the `*` signified that it is processing. I have given it ample time, and it is only a simple print statement, which should process immediately.

[image]

Additional information that may be useful.
Pipfile

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
numpy = "*"
matplotlib = "*"
pytest = "*"
setuptools = "*"
cycler = "*"
kiwisolver = "*"
pyparsing = "*"
jupyter = "*"
ipython = "*"
nbformat = "*"
jupytext = "*"
jupyter-kernel-gateway = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

Ouput of `jupyter troubleshoot`

```
$PATH:
    /Users/harvest/.local/share/virtualenvs/make-your-own-neural-network-3AgNnsP-/bin
    /Users/harvest/.local/share/virtualenvs/make-your-own-neural-network-3AgNnsP-/bin
    /Users/harvest/.yarn/bin
    /Users/harvest/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin
    /Users/harvest/.pyenv/shims
    /Users/harvest/.nodenv/shims
    /Users/harvest/.rbenv/shims
    /Users/harvest/bin
    /usr/local/bin
    /usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_1/libexec/tools
    /Users/harvest/.yarn/bin
    /Users/harvest/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin
    /Users/harvest/.pyenv/shims
    /Users/harvest/.nodenv/shims
    /Users/harvest/.rbenv/shims
    /Users/harvest/bin
    /usr/local/bin
    /usr/local/bin
    /usr/bin
    /bin
    /usr/sbin
    /sbin
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
    /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
    /Users/harvest/.composer/vendor/bin
    /Users/harvest/.composer/vendor/bin

sys.path:
    /Users/harvest/.local/share/virtualenvs/make-your-own-neural-network-3AgNnsP-/bin
    /Users/harvest/.local/share/virtualenvs/make-your-own-neural-network-3AgNnsP-/lib/python37.zip
    /Users/harvest/.local/share/virtualenvs/make-your-own-neural-network-3AgNnsP-/lib/python3.7
    /Users/harvest/.local/share/virtualenvs/make-your-own-neural-network-3AgNnsP-/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
    /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7
    /Users/harvest/.local/share/virtualenvs/make-your-own-neural-network-3AgNnsP-/lib/python3.7/site-packages

sys.executable:
    /Users/harvest/.local/share/virtualenvs/make-your-own-neural-network-3AgNnsP-/bin/python3.7

sys.version:
    3.7.2 (default, Jan 13 2019, 12:50:01) 
    [Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)]

platform.platform():
    Darwin-18.2.0-x86_64-i386-64bit

which -a jupyter:
    /Users/harvest/.local/share/virtualenvs/make-your-own-neural-network-3AgNnsP-/bin/jupyter
    /Users/harvest/.local/share/virtualenvs/make-your-own-neural-network-3AgNnsP-/bin/jupyter

pip list:
    Package                Version    
    ---------------------- -----------
    appnope                0.1.0      
    atomicwrites           1.3.0      
    attrs                  19.1.0     
    backcall               0.1.0      
    bleach                 3.1.0      
    certifi                2018.11.29 
    chardet                3.0.4      
    cycler                 0.10.0     
    decorator              4.3.2      
    defusedxml             0.5.0      
    entrypoints            0.3        
    freetype-py            2.0.0.post6
    idna                   2.8        
    ipykernel              5.1.0      
    ipython                7.3.0      
    ipython-genutils       0.2.0      
    ipywidgets             7.4.2      
    jedi                   0.13.3     
    Jinja2                 2.10       
    jsonschema             3.0.1      
    jupyter                1.0.0      
    jupyter-client         5.2.4      
    jupyter-console        6.0.0      
    jupyter-core           4.4.0      
    jupyter-kernel-gateway 2.2.0      
    jupytext               1.0.2      
    kiwisolver             1.0.1      
    MarkupSafe             1.1.1      
    matplotlib             3.0.3      
    mistune                0.8.4      
    mock                   2.0.0      
    more-itertools         6.0.0      
    nbconvert              5.4.1      
    nbformat               4.4.0      
    notebook               5.7.4      
    numpy                  1.16.2     
    pandocfilters          1.4.2      
    parso                  0.3.4      
    pbr                    5.1.3      
    pexpect                4.6.0      
    pickleshare            0.7.5      
    pip                    19.0.3     
    pluggy                 0.9.0      
    prometheus-client      0.6.0      
    prompt-toolkit         2.0.9      
    ptyprocess             0.6.0      
    py                     1.8.0      
    Pygments               2.3.1      
    pyparsing              2.3.1      
    pyrsistent             0.14.11    
    pytest                 4.3.0      
    python-dateutil        2.8.0      
    PyYAML                 3.13       
    pyzmq                  18.0.0     
    qtconsole              4.4.3      
    requests               2.21.0     
    Send2Trash             1.5.0      
    setuptools             40.8.0     
    six                    1.12.0     
    terminado              0.8.1      
    testfixtures           6.6.0      
    testpath               0.4.2      
    tornado                6.0        
    traitlets              4.3.2      
    urllib3                1.24.1     
    wcwidth                0.1.7      
    webencodings           0.5.1      
    wheel                  0.33.1     
    widgetsnbextension     3.4.2
```

Comment: I am new to Jupyter, however just noticed the icon beside the Python 3, below the log-out button is different than mine. For me, it was a circle outline which means kernel is idle, and when I run codes (while waiting for the output) it becomes shaded, which means kernel is busy. Maybe you should check what that icon means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this by Uninstalling tornado 6 and installing tornado 5.

`5.1.1` is the last stable version and fixed my problem.

Referenced from [Jupyter notebook: No connection to server because websocket connection fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54963043/jupyter-notebook-no-connection-to-server-because-websocket-connection-fails)